# How would the displacement of an object be calculated using only initial speed, coefficient of kinetic friction and the slope of the hill?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A sled takes off from the top of a hill inclined at 6.0° to the horizontal. The sled’s initial speed is 12 m/s. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the sled and the snow is 0.14. Determine how far the sled will slide before coming to rest.

So based on this question, my three known variables are θ = 6°, vᵢ = 12 m/s and μₖ = 0.14. I've made an FBD for this problem but it's not helping, my main problem is that I don't know how to use those 3 variable in order to obtain my answer.

*Edit*: added my FBD:

[image: FBD for the problem]

Comment: Hint: The rate at which energy is lost to friction is constant.

Answer (score 1):

We do not solve homework and exercise questions on this site. The following is offered only for guidance.

The loss of kinetic+ potential energy of the sled will equal the friction work done by the incline plane on the sled. Set the two equal to each other and solve for the distance $d$ It will slide down the incline.

Hope this helps.